# any custom openstack centos image with a set password i can use?

Tags: image, centos, openstack

I have to do some quick benchmarking. 
I am unable to my vms since neutron is not setup properly. 
I can create centos vm.. but i can not log into it. 
I tried adding keypair, i tried could init change root password

```
#cloud-config
chpasswd:
 list: |
   root:stackops
   centos:stackops
 expire: False
```

it does not  work. I mean it did not give any errors on log console but i am not abel to login with the credentials i set.

So my question is ..where can i find a openstack centos 7 image whose password is already set ( i guess it would be a custom one)

Answer (score 1):

If Neutron isn't set up correctly, you're not going to be able to do much with your OpenStack environment.  However, even with broken networking, you can pass your `user-data` script to the instance using the `--config-drive` option, e.g:

```
nova boot --user-data /path/to/config.yaml --config-drive=true ...
```

There is a checkbox in the Horizon gui to use this feature as well.  This attaches your configuration as a virtual CD-ROM device, which `cloud-init` will use rather than the network metadata service.

If I put your cloud-config into a file called `user-data.yaml`, and then run:

```
nova boot --image centos-7-cloud --user-data user-data.yaml centos
```

Then I can log in as the `centos` user using the password `stackops`.

Comment: larsks can i pass a gunzip file using --condog-drive ?

Comment: Sure.  You can use the `--file` argument to `nova boot` to include arbitrary files. Metadata about the files will be in `openstack/latest/meta_data.json` in the `files` key, and content will be in `openstack/content/`.

Comment: thanks .. i am trying to install a package onevery vm that is created ( since they do not have network /neutron..i was htinking of passing a gzip file to vm and installing it using cloud init) .. doable ?